# How many times a function was called (even/odd number of times)

Tags: javascript, function

I am doing an exercise and depending on the number of times the function was called, a different result should be returned. If the function for example was called 0,1,2 times, it should return a number (see below), if it was called more than 3 times AND is odd (called 3 times, the third time called =odd) then it should return a string, etc. I know how I would do it if it was just called once or not at all, but I can't figure out how to write the code for odd/even times..

This part was provided and should NOT be changed:

```
var plus = function (a,b) {
    return a+b;
}
var func = sometimes(plus); 

var array = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    array.push(func(2+i,3+i)) //should return [7,9,11, 'no idea']     
}
```

This is the function I wrote and is clearly wrong..

```
function sometimes (newFunc){
    var called = newFunc();
    if (called>4) {
        return newFunc;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

Comment: You are using a variable `called` (which would probably better be named `count` or `calledCount` or something), but initializing it to the value returned by `newFunc()`. Instead, you want to initialize that variable to zero, then **return a function**, inside of which you do the check and return the right value.

Comment: the question is how can I do that for odd even times called??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this suits your issue, but give it a try running the code snippet below.

```js
var selfInvokeFunc = (function (func) {
    var counter = 0;
    return function (func) {
        if (counter >= 3 && counter % 2 != 0) {
           counter++;
           return "'no idea'";
        }
        else {
            counter++;
            return func;
        }
    }
})();

var plus = function (a,b) {
    return a+b;
}
var func = function (a, b) {
    return selfInvokeFunc(plus(a+1,b+1));
}

var array = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    array.push(func(2+i,3+i));   
}
alert(array); //should return [7,9,11,'no idea',15,'no idea',19,'no idea']
document.write(array);
```

That should return [7,9,11,'no idea',15,'no idea',19,'no idea'] whereas

array[0] = 7,

array[1] = 9,

array[2] = 11,

array[3] = 'no idea', //3rd times called

array[4] = 15,

array[5] = 'no idea', // Odd

array[6] = 19,

array[7] = 'no idea' // Odd

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks. You say here when counter===3 then return no idea, but I need to do it for ALL ODD numbers (not only for 3, but also for 5,7 etc) and thats what I didn't know-how to include number%2==0 in it

Comment: @juliascoding changing (counter%2 != 0) doesn't work in your case?

Comment: I tried that (but doesn't work too):  function sometimes() {
    var count = 0;
    var closureFunc = function() {
        if (count < 3) {
            count++;
            return newFunc;
        } else if (count >= 3) {
            if (count % 2 == 0) {
                count++;
                return newFunc;
            } else {
                count++;
                return 'I do not know!';
            }
        }
    }
    return closureFunc;
}

Comment: I'm afraid I am now a little confused, what is exactly your expected result then?
not [7,9,11, 'no idea'] ?

Comment: the expected result is  [7,9,11, 'no idea']

Comment: Thank you. You created a self-invoking function and I wonder if that is the only way to create closures so the counter variable doesn't always get set back to 0? I 've seen examples where you can do that without that self-invoking function and wonder if that wouldn't be possible in this case.